# Symfony2 checkbox form, alter date based on a checkbox

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, checkbox

For test purposes I make a light library online tool with Symfony2.

I have a `Borrow` entity that links to other entities. I want to create a form to validate the return of the books a given user have borrowed.

I have gathered all the `Borrow` recordings that correspond to books the user has not returned.

Now I want to create a form with a checkbox list to validate the books the user has returned.
After that, I can make something like what follows (which is not the problem).

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $obj_list = $form->getData();
        foreach ($obj_list as $obj)
        {
                $obj->setBorrowEndDate(...); // Today's datetime

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($obj);
                $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
    }
    else
    {
        $args['problem']=$form->errors();
    }
}
// Continuation : creation of the form
```

Comment: I wish I could help you but I really don't understand the question.

Comment: I can create a form and link it to an Object in database to modify data fields. But I want to make a checkbox to update an object. When this checkbox is on and the form sent, I want to update the object's date_return to today. Does this help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem but i'll try to help you:

**1)** Create a class attribute in your Entity (Borrow) called "check" for example, which is not depending on your databases:

```
private $check;

public function setCheck($check)
{
     $this->check = $check;
}

public function getCheck()
{
     return $this->check;
}
```

**2)** Add it in your class form as a checkbox input.

```
$builder->add('check', 'checkbox')
```

**3)** Then, you've got 2 solutions:

Update its setter like this:

```
public function setCheck($check)
{
    $this->check = $check;

    // Update borrow endtime
    if ($this->check === true && !$this->getBorrowEndDate()) {
        $this->setBorrowEndDate(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

Or use doctrine [lifecycles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks):

```
/**
   * Called before persisting your entity
   * 
   * @ORM\prePersist
   */
public function prePersist()
{
    // Update borrow endtime
    if ($this->check === true && !$this->getBorrowEndDate()) {
         $this->setBorrowEndDate(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating entity attribute, you can do it in this way:

```
    $builder->add('check', 'checkbox', [
        'mapped' => false
    ]);


    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $object = $event->getData();

        if($form->get('check')->getData() && !$object->getBorrowEndDate()) {
            $object->setBorrowEndDate(new \DateTime());
        }

        $event->setData($object);
    });
```